# filter an Array using multiple elements and a logical operator

Tags: arrays, scala, filter

I have a 2D array as follows:

```
scala> testme4
res15: Array[(java.sql.Timestamp, Int, Int, Boolean)] 
   = Array((2016-11-17 15:18:50.47,13,-8,false), 
           (2016-11-17 15:18:51.37,21,-1,false), 
           (2016-11-17 15:18:51.37,22,-1,false), 
           (2016-11-17 15:18:51.86,23,-1,false), 
           (2016-11-17 15:18:52.3,24,22,false), 
           (2016-11-17 15:18:52.37,2,-2,false), 
           (2016-11-17 15:18:54.2,4,-1,false), 
           (2016-11-17 15:18:54.2,5,-7,false), 
           (2016-11-17 15:20:57.27,12,-4,false), 
           (2016-11-17 15:20:57.67,16,-1,false), 
           (2016-11-17 15:20:57.67,17,-9,false), 
           (2016-11-17 15:20:58.3,26,0,false), 
           (2016-11-17 15:20:59.35,26,0,true)
       )
```

I want select (filter) to get all elements other then "2016-11-17 15:20:58.3,26,0,false"

I need to do this using the 3rd and 4th sub-elements of each element ... by filtereing on (pseudo code):

_3 != 0 OR _4==true

The two predicates work fine in a filter on their own:

```
scala> testme4.filter(_._3 != 0 ) 
res16: Array[(java.sql.Timestamp, Int, Int, Boolean)] 
   = Array((2016-11-17 15:18:50.47,13,-8,false),
           (2016-11-17 15:18:51.37,21,-1,false),
           (2016-11-17 15:18:51.37,22,-1,false), 
           (2016-11-17 15:18:51.86,23,-1,false), 
           (2016-11-17 15:18:52.3,24,22,false), 
           (2016-11-17 15:18:52.37,2,-2,false), 
           (2016-11-17 15:18:54.2,4,-1,false), 
           (2016-11-17 15:18:54.2,5,-7,false), 
           (2016-11-17 15:20:57.27,12,-4,false), 
           (2016-11-17 15:20:57.67,16,-1,false), 
           (2016-11-17 15:20:57.67,17,-9,false)
       )
```

or..

```
scala> testme4.filter(_._4) 
res17: Array[(java.sql.Timestamp, Int, Int, Boolean)] 
        = Array((2016-11-17 15:20:59.35,26,0,true))
```

But if I try to combine them with a logical operator I get an error :

```
scala> testme4.filter(_._3 != 0 || _._4) 
<console>:38: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1, x$2) => x$1._3.$bang$eq(0).$bar$bar(x$2._4))
   testme4.filter(_._3 != 0 || _._4)
```

Does anyone have any idea why this error occurs?, and how I can achieve the simple Logical Operation with the filter ?

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use use `testme4.filter(i => i._3 != 0 || i._4)`.

For `_._3 != 0 || _._4` it's causing the confusion for **compiler** to infer the second type. As the compiler **thrown**, the compiler is trying to convert:

```
_._3 != 0 || _._4
```

to

```
((x$1, x$2) => x$1._3.$bang$eq(0).$bar$bar(x$2._4))
```

for `x$2`, the **compiler** could not infer this, so this **compiler error** thrown.

Comment: The fix is correct but I still slightly disagree with the explanation. `_` must  be used once and exactly once for each function argument. As such, writing `_._3 != 0 || _._4`, the compiler will create a function expecting two arguments. It is very different from `i => i._3 != 0 || i._4` which is clearly a function expecting only a single argument.

Comment: Hi @FredericA., As you said: "_ must be used once and exactly once for each function argument." so for `_` should be used as **minimum** context, when use `_._3 != 0 || _._4` this in context, it's causing confusion for compiler.

Comment: Many Thanks for the help and the explanations :-)